# How to count filtered rows with where clause in t-sql?

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, sql, t-sql

Given the Table below. I need to count the number of rows for every records which have values in **SubCategory** column as "**Children's Books**" using transact SQL. In this case, I expect a result of 2. I tried something like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From [DisplayCenterTab] Where [SubCategory ]= '" + subcateg + "' ", con);
```

but it is returning zero(0) result instead of 2. What am I missing here? Thanks

My Table:

```
Id        ProductId       ProductName      Category            SubCategory
34534     34643645        dfhfsjfdjgh      sdfagdsfhfhgfhj     dfgsdhhgfh
45234     456436          fghdfjfgj        dfgsdhfhfgfgh       Children's Books
46536     45646           fgjdgjfgh        dfgshfgfdghj        Children's Books
43645     466456          systyerttry      sdhdfhfggjh         dfhshfdjgfgh
34526     456345          areyruuty        dfshfdfgjghj        dafgshfghgfh
```

**Update**

JQuery Code

```
$("#sellstuff").click(function () {
    var dataObject = $("#scrolldummy").text();
    //var dataObject = "Children's Books";
    $.getJSON("/OnlineStore/TotalNumberofSubCateg", dataObject, function (data) {
        $("#search").val(data + " Assorted Items for Sale.");
    });
})
```

C# Code

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult TotalNumberofSubCateg(string subcateg)
        {
            int rowcount;
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StockConnString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DisplayCenterTab Where SubCategory = '"+ subcateg +"' ", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            rowcount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
            return Json(rowcount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: How are you calling it and catching the return value? Can you please post the code?

Comment: @felix Pammitan  I'm using json result in C# to return the value and jQuery $.getJSON({...}) command. Do you want to see them?

Comment: That would certainly help. Please post the C# code.

Comment: Hey Felix, pls see my updates. Thanks

Comment: please check the value for subcateg using debug mode.

Comment: @thejustv Yup and I got it resolved. I actually messed up with my client script declaration of my dataObject variable which was the reason why it catches null subcateg variable. It should have had my class model define in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks..It's my mess actually.Here's an update to my question. I don't have actually an issue with my sql statement but it's actually my client script variable declaration. I forgot to remember that in your client script your dataObject variable should had your class model variable. I post this update so anybody doesn't know or haven't been yet able to encounter this type of problem would know them ahead.

```
 $("#sellstuff").click(function () {

    var dataObject =
        { SubCategory: $("#scrolldummy").text() };

    $.getJSON("/OnlineStore/TotalNumberofSubCateg", dataObject, function (data) {
        $("#search").val(data + " Assorted Items for Sale.");
    });

})



 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult TotalNumberofSubCateg(string SubCategory)
    {
        int rowcount;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StockConnString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DisplayCenterTab Where SubCategory = '"+ SubCategory.Replace("'","''") +"' ", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        rowcount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        return Json(rowcount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to escape single quote character from the `subcateg` variable.
try this

```
    SqlCommand cmd = 
new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From [DisplayCenterTab] Where [SubCategory ]= '" + subcateg.Replace("'","''") + "' ", con);
```

Comment: I have tried that too but it is returning a null value.

Comment: that is weird. getting `null` returned for `count` is strange.  did you try to see the query prepared at runtime?

Comment: Yeah, I think there's something missing on my client script here. I'm looking closely on it now.

Comment: You still need to have the fix suggested in my answer to escape single quote `'`, otherwise it will give you unexpected output

Comment: You know that's kinda wondering about this. If I tried subcateg.Replace("'","''") it will give a null value. If I just missed out the Replace method it will return 0 value...Hmmm. I'm suspecting on my client script here.

Comment: Can you please post the query that is generated at run time?

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use command parameter in your queries, it handles everything. Here is your code rewritten:

```
    public JsonResult TotalNumberofSubCateg(string subcateg)
    {
        int rowcount;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StockConnString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DisplayCenterTab Where SubCategory = @S0 ", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S0", subcateg ); // it will handle the string format
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        rowcount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        return Json(rowcount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Normally, this should work, but i haven't tested it out.

Comment: So Let me test them with stored pro.. let's see if it works..Hold on

Comment: Nope, it would still return null value. I'm not sure why it's not catching the string param called subcate.

Comment: start by checking if rowcount is greater than 0, if so you are having a problem with the return json line. if rowcount = 0, then your query is not good

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your **single quote** `'` with **double quote** `''` in `SQL` like:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = 
new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From [DisplayCenterTab] Where [SubCategory ]= 'Children''s Books' ", con)
```

Comment: Let me update my codes to call and catching values using json result in C# and jquery.Hold on